Meta API: 100% Call Count Usage with gr:get:InvalidID Endpoint – What Does It Mean?
I’m using the Meta API for ad management reports, config changes and campaigns creation, and I’ve noticed that my app is at 100% Call Count Usage Rate in the Developer Dashboard. Surprisingly, my API requests still work, but the dashboard shows the most-used endpoint is gr:get:InvalidID.
gr:get:InvalidID

I couldn’t find documentation on what gr:get:InvalidID represents. Here are my questions:
1.  What is the gr:get: InvalidID endpoint, and why might it appear as the most used?
2.  How can I trace or debug what caused these requests?
3.  Does the Meta API provide logs or tools to view detailed API request data?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue and understand its impact would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
